# Bash / JQ - cant assign pull string and assign variable

Tags: bash, adb, jq

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to pull a command from a json file and use it in the script

Here is the data.json

```
"play_music": {
            "name": "play_music",
            "command" : "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///${device_directory}${music_file} -t audio/${audio_type}",
            "variables" : {
                "device_directory" : {
                    "name" : "device_directory",
                    "variable" : "/Downloads/"
                },
                "music_file" : {
                    "name" : "music_file",
                    "variable" : "test.mp3"
                },
                "audio_type" : {
                    "name" : "audio_type",
                    "variable" : "mp3"
                }
            }
```

And here is a snippet of code that I am trying to get to run the command

```
while true; do
    variables=( $(jq -r ".commands.$option.variables | map(.name) | .[]" data.json))
    ##echo ${variables[@]}
    
    for i in ${variables[@]}; do
        ##echo -e "\n$i"
        var=$(jq -r ".commands.$option.variables.$i.variable" data.json)
        if [[ -z $var ]]; then
            ##echo -e "var is empty"
            echo -e "Enter $i: "
            read $i
        else
            ##echo -e "var is full"
            declare $i=$var
        fi
    done

echo -e "\nmusic file='${music_file}'"
echo -e "\naudio type='${audio_type}'"
echo ""

command="$(jq -r ".commands.$option.command" data.json)"
echo $command
```

The variables report as

```
music file='test.mp3'

audio type='mp3'
```

The command just comes back as:
`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///${device_directory}${music_file} -t audio/${audio_type}`
But what I am looking for is
`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:////Downloads/test.mp3 -t audio/mp3`

I tried running outputting the command in different forms $(command), "$command", etc but have had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not very elegant (see **More Elegant** below), and I'm confident you'll get a better answer, but it's possible for `jq` to form the `command` string in one go using a filter like this.  Perhaps you can adapt it for your application.

```
.commands.play_music
| .command as $cmd
| .variables
  | .device_directory.variable as $dir
  | .music_file.variable as $file
  | .audio_type.variable as $type
| $cmd
| sub("\\${device_directory}"; $dir)
| sub("\\${music_file}"; $file)
| sub("\\${audio_type}"; $type)
```

Output using your probable input:

```
"adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:////Downloads/test.mp3 -t audio/mp3"
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/pCWP6phsvbN).

##### More Elegant

The same output is produced by this filter and is perhaps more adaptable to your application.

```
.commands.play_music
| (.variables|map({k: .name, v: .variable})) as $vars
| reduce $vars[] as $var (.command; .|sub("\\${\($var.k)}"; $var.v))
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/Bz3xY99I64d).

... and more incomprehensibly as:

```
.commands.play_music
| reduce .variables[] as $var (.command; .|sub("\\${\($var.name)}"; $var.variable))
```

... still outputs:

```
"adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:////Downloads/test.mp3 -t audio/mp3"
```

Try this on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/7OVHbGldgIr).

Comment: `sub` only replaces one occurrence of a variable. Use `gsub` if it is possible for the same variable to be used multiple times in the command.

Comment: The "More Elegant" solution works perfectly for my question. Is there any way I could use this:

"jq '.commands.play_music | (.variables|map({k: .name, v: .variable})) as $vars | reduce $vars[] as $var (.command; .|sub("\\${\($var.k)}"; $var.v)) '"

But replace the .command.<command_name> with a variable?

Comment: @Siân There are lots of ways to do that.  One way might be to invoke `jq` like: `jq --arg cmd play_music '.commands[$cmd] |  ... '`.

Comment: You rock! Thank you, that works perfectly in my use case

Answer (score 1):

The shell's parameter expansion is not recursive.  When it expands `$command`, you just get its replacement text, as is.

You *could* get a second round a parameter expansion -- and all other expansions, redirections, *etc*. -- by running the resulting command text with `eval` instead of directly:

```
eval "$command"
```

That expands `"$command"` normally, then evaluates the result as if it were shell input.

`eval` is dangerous and tricky.  Especially so when applied to data obtained externally from the script in which the `eval`uation is taking place.  I think what you're trying to accomplish is too clever by half, yet not half as well engineered as it should be for something of its kind.  I do not recommend proceeding down this path.

Moreover, it's unclear what you think you're gaining from the internal parameterization, as the variable values are tightly associated with the command.  There's no customization available that way without editing the file, and if you're going to do that then you might as well just edit the command directly.